# How do I override the login_path that Devise uses when user not authenticated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

This is what my `devise` routes look like:

```
  devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_up => "register",
                                      :sign_in => "login",
                                      :sign_out => "logout",
                                          :settings => "settings" },
                    :controllers => { :invitations => 'users/invitations',
                                      :registrations => "registrations" }
  devise_scope :user do
    get "login", to: "devise/sessions#new"
    get "register", to: "devise/registrations#new"
        get "settings", to: "devise/registrations#edit"
    delete "logout", to: "devise/sessions#destroy"
    post "users/invitation/sign_in", to: "users/invitations#invite_sign_in"
    get "confirmations/show"

    authenticated :user do
      root to: 'dashboard#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

When I do `rake routes`, I see this:

```
login_path  GET /login(.:format)    devise/sessions#new
register_path   GET /register(.:format) devise/registrations#new
settings_path   GET /settings(.:format) devise/registrations#edit
```

Which is what I would expect.

However, once I add this to my controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

I get a redirect loop when an unauthenticated user tries to access that resource.

Here is the log:

```
5:48:59 web.1              | Started GET "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 15:48:59 -0500
15:48:59 web.1              | Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
15:48:59 web.1              |   Parameters: {"id"=>"login"}
15:48:59 web.1              | Completed 401 Unauthorized in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
15:48:59 web.1              | 
15:48:59 web.1              | 
15:48:59 web.1              | Started GET "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 15:48:59 -0500
15:48:59 web.1              | Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
15:48:59 web.1              |   Parameters: {"id"=>"login"}
15:48:59 web.1              | Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Rather than have it redirect to `/users/login`, how do I let it redirect to `/login`?

Not quite sure how to override this particular functionality. Not seeing it in any of the Devise docs.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you happen to have `resources :users` on top of the `devise` routes? May be they are interfering with the devise routes. Also try to `get "/login", to: "devise/sessions#new"` instead of `get "login", to: "devise/sessions#new"` and see if it works.

Comment: @Dharam I actually do have `resources :users` above that `devise` routes. Should I move it to below it? Just tried `/login/` and that didn't fix it.

Comment: @Dharam You were right. Once I moved that `resources :users` down below the `devise` routes, it works. Thanks much. Add that as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you happen to have `resources :users` on top of the devise routes? May be they are interfering with the devise routes.

Also try to get `"/login", to: "devise/sessions#new"` instead of `get "login", to: "devise/sessions#new"` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly...you could write a custom before_filter:

```
 def user_is_authenticated?
   unless current_user.present?
     # whatever else you want to do
     redirect_to login_path
   end
 end
```

Lmk if this isn't what you meant.